# PHP import csv to mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, file, csv

I have a csv file with almost 8000 lines. I need to insert som e columns to the database. For that I am using the below code:

```
$csv_file = $_FILES[file][tmp_name];
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile))
{
        $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
        $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
        $insert_csv = array();
        $insert_csv['code'] = $csv_array[6];
        $insert_csv['description'] = $csv_array[7];
        $insert_csv['rrp'] =$csv_array[8];
        $insert_csv['buy'] = $csv_array[9];
        $insert_csv['stock'] = $csv_array[11];
        if($insert_csv['code']!="" && $insert_csv['description']!="" && $insert_csv['rrp']!="" || $insert_csv['buy']!="" || $insert_csv['stock']!="")
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO pricing (code, description,rrp,buy,stock,distributor,vendor,version) VALUES
                     ('".$insert_csv['code']."','".$insert_csv['description']."','".$insert_csv['rrp']."','".$insert_csv['buy']."','".$insert_csv['stock']."',
                     '".$d."','".$v."','".$version."')";
            $n=mysql_query($query, $con);
        }
        $i++;
}
    fclose($csvfile);
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;
```

But the issues is, sometimes some columns itself has comma separated values. So the insertion of database is difficult using my code. So the insertion of values will be wrong column values.

Eg:

correct csv data:(This will insert correctly to the database)

**2132,JUNIPER,CONTENT SUBSCRIPTIONS,First Year Subscriptions,A,GEN,SRX220-IDP,1 year license for IDP updates for SRX 220,951.3514,599.3514,37%,0,0,0,0,31/10/13 21:16,0,21**

But sometimes the csv file contains the following line format:

Here the $csv_array[2] itself has comma separated values but covered with quotes. My code is only looking for commas. SO the insertion values will be different in the db table.

**2132,JUNIPER,"J, SRX, AX, VGW",Base System,A,GEN,AX411-KR,Dual Radio 802.11abgn Access Point for Korea. Power supply not included.,805.4054,507.4054,37.01%,0,0,0,0,31/10/13 21:16,0,21**

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
if ($_FILES[file][size] > 0)
        {
            //get the csv file
            $file = $_FILES[file][tmp_name];
            $handle = fopen($file,"r");
            fgetcsv($handle,10000,",");
            //loop through the csv file and insert into database
            do
            {
                if ($data[0])
                {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pricing (code, description,rrp,buy,stock,distributor,vendor,version) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                    '".$d."',
                    '".$v."',
                    '".$version."'
                )
            ");
                }
            } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',','"'));

            header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring quotes in the file.  php's [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) allows you to read a file from a csv file, and it will honor quotes around strings

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = '\\' ]]]] )
```

Adapted to your use case (using commas for separation and double quotes around strings) that's used as

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvfile, 1000, ",",'"')) !== FALSE) {
```

Superficially reading CSV files looks very easy, in reality there are many special cases to consider, that's why using the standard, well tested and versatile functions is always your best option.

Comment: I have checked my csv file in text editor. But not every fields are covered with double quotes. Is there any problem?

Comment: @NewPHP no, see [RFC4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) which is as close to a standard as one can get for CSV paragraphs 2.5 2.6 and 2.7.  Quotes are optional except for fields containing double quotes, commas and line breaks - and that's in your case only so for the second field so it's okay to only doublequote that field.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `csv` functions instead `explode`.

- [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
- [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
- [SplFileObject::fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php)

Or even load csv file directly to mysql

- [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

Example from manual to skip some columns

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

Comment: I haven't tried LOAD DATA INFILE before. Using this command how can I insert selected columns to the database? Is this possible?

Comment: Upload file to a, lets say, `/tmp` folder (accessible by all system users) and use something like this `LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' INTO TABLE pricing FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

Comment: Let me have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the best code for importing a CSV file into mysql with no duplicate records, and it shows results on how many records were inserted and how many are duplicates

```
<?php
    $duplicate=0;
    $record=0;
    $total=0;
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","","","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("svn",$conn);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $handle=fopen($file,"r");
    while(($fileop=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
    {
    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    {
    $fn= addslashes ($fileop[0]);
    $ln=addslashes ($fileop[1]);
    $ti=addslashes ($fileop[2]);
    $ac=addslashes ($fileop[3]);
    $em=addslashes ($fileop[4]);
    $op=addslashes ($fileop[5]);
    $mp=addslashes ($fileop[6]);
    $fx=addslashes ($fileop[7]);
    $ad=addslashes ($fileop[8]);
    $co=addslashes ($fileop[9]);
    $st=addslashes ($fileop[10]);
    $ci=addslashes ($fileop[11]);
    $zc=addslashes ($fileop[12]);
    }
    else
    {
    $fn= $fileop[0];
    $ln=$fileop[1];
    $ti=$fileop[2];
    $ac=$fileop[3];
    $em=$fileop[4];
    $op=$fileop[5];
    $mp=$fileop[6];
    $fx=$fileop[7];
    $ad=$fileop[8];
    $co=$fileop[9];
    $st=$fileop[10];
    $ci=$fileop[11];
    $zc=$fileop[12];
    }


    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE email='$em'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
      {

       $duplicate=$duplicate+1;
      }
    else
      {
      $record=$record+1;
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(first_name,last_name,title,account,email,officephone,mobphone,fax,address,country,state,city,zipcode) 
    VALUES('$fn','$ln','$ti','$ac','$em','$op','$mp','$fx','$ad','$co','$st','$ci','$zc')");
    }
    }

    echo"Data inserted successfully";

    echo "<table width='600' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>"."<td>"."Record inserted"."</td>"."<td>".$record."</td>"."</tr>";
    echo "<tr>"."<td>"."duplicate record"."</td>"."<td>".$duplicate."</td>"."</tr>";
    echo "<tr>"."<td>"."Total records"."</td>"."<td>".$total=$record + $duplicate."</td>"."</tr>";
    echo "</table>";


    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?
    $duplicate=0;
    $record=0;
    $total=0;
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file" value="selectfile"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```